# Geocoder leaflet for internal use in the company, which take addresses from any part of the street

Tags: geocoding, leaflet

I am making a personal application routing to be used internally in the company using machine leaflet route. 
The plugin uses nominatim geocoder, but he geocodificia according to the links of the OSM. I need to get the long / lat of arbitrary points, for example if the A Street No. 1234 is in the middle of the block on the corner geocode returns. That for purposes of mileage will make a difference to me.

Would like suggestions of geocoder that meet this need, remembering that the application is built.